# Filling a QListWidget with elements from a dynamic list

Tags: python, list, pyqt, qlistwidget

I created a `QListWidget`in QtDesigner and i want to add it some items from another list called "list_1" that i created before . The thing is that, that list(`list_1`) is updating every time i press a combination of keys.

Here is the code:

```
class Win(self):
  list_1 = []
  number = 0                   #This is a variable that is continuously changing
  def __init__(self):
    #Some stuff in here

  def addItem(self):
    item = "Number " + str(Win.number)
    Win.list_1.append(item)
    Win.number += 1

class Dialog(QDialog):
   def __init__(self):
     QDialog._init__(self):
     uic.loadUi("ListWidget.ui", self)

   def addItems(self):
     #I want to create this method to add the items from list_1 into the `QListWidget`
```

How can i do to open the `QDialog`(with a button that i already have) and see in the QListWidget the items as they are appended in the list. I mean, "i open the `QDialog` and i see Number 1. Then, i close the `QDialog`, add a number to the list and when i open the `QDialog`again i can see `Number 1`and `Number 2`, and so on.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Typically you'd use a QListView and an item model for this rather than a QListWidget.  As you add items to the model, the view gets updated.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I need to do this with a `QlistWidget` to add some others functions later. I´ve made a for loop
for i in list_1:
item = QListWidgetItem(i)
self.listWidget.addItem(item)

but it does not update when i create a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to use the Model/View architecture, you have two options.

### 1. Build/refresh the QListWidget every time you show it.

Unless you have thousands of items or have complex custom painting for each of the items, this will be pretty fast.

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, list_1):
        QDialog._init__(self):
        uic.loadUi("ListWidget.ui", self)
        for txt in list_1:
            QListWidgetItem(txt, self.list_widget)
```

### 2. Use the QListWidgetItems as your "model".

Don't even bother keeping a separate list.  Directly edit the `QListWidgetItems` in the `QListWidget`.  This only works if you're not destroying and creating the `QDialog` every time.

In the long run, I think you'll find this method works better.  You'll be tearing down and refreshing the GUI less (which means it will be faster), and you won't have to deal with bugs where the source list was updated but not the GUI (and vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first one is simpler that the one i made. Thank you again, it helped me a lot.